# Detect certain image in the clipboard

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

Is there a way to detect if an image from a folder was copied to the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`flash.desktop.Clipboard`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/Clipboard.html).
To obtain the clipboard contents as a reference, you'll need `FILE_LIST_FORMAT` or `URL_FORMAT`, both of which are AIR only.

Comment: But is there a listener for it? I want to enable a button after something is pasted to the clipboard.

Comment: AIR does not allow event triggers out of focus, so a listener would be useless in your case. However, you could check the clipboard when your application receives a `FocusEvent`, and enable the button then. You could also rethink the functionality, and see if you can implement it without checking the clipboard.